How to insert stream of large amount of small data into DB in Node.js cost effectively?
Data is received every 50ms from a single entity as a byte stream. After transforming and batching, the data is shaped into objects similar to the following:
{
  id: "000000000000001",
  eventTime: "2024-11-11T11:11:11.111+00:00",
  data: [{
    timestamp: "1731319871",
    object1: {
      key1: 1,
      key2: "2",
      ...
    },
    object2: {
      key1: "1",
      key2: 2.1,
      ...
    }
  },
  ...]
}

The data array typically has a length of around 20, representing one second of data (since data arrives every 50ms).
There are five types of objects, and each type is meant to be inserted into a different table. Consequently, each entity triggers five inserts every second.
My goal is to handle data from 1,000 entities in one Node.js application, resulting in 5 * 1,000 = 5,000 inserts per second. After achieving this, I plan to scale up to 10,000 entities by running 10 instances of the application.
I attempted to manage 500 entities using MongoDB's insertMany(), but it could not keep up with the incoming data. Upon monitoring performance, I noticed that the insert count was double (5,000) compared to the expected 2,500 (5 * 500). I tried setting up a sharded MongoDB with two shards, but it was still slow. Additionally, the cost of a managed sharded MongoDB solution would be prohibitively expensive.
I also experimented with PostgreSQL, using the JSON type for the data column, but its performance was worse than MongoDB.
As an alternative, I considered writing the incoming data to a JSON file, which would solve the storage issue, but I need to analyze the data by ID in near real-time.

Can you provide the DDL and query you used for Postgresql? It surprises me that it wasn't able to handle 500 inserts/sec, particularly since it seems like you don't have any heavy indexes.

Since this is time-series data, I'd look at a time-series database, e.g. TimescaleDB, InfluxDB, VictoriaMetrics maybe. But you'll need to process the JSON into something more palatable.

500 entities produce 2500 rows per second and this amount of data can be arrived for hours.I used the query builder of typeorm  (https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/insert-query-builder)

If you need raw performance, avoid an ORM and query builder and prepare a statement in advance, then execute it repeatedly as your data comes in.

(And if you really, really do need raw performance, Node.js is likely not the right choice of language...)

Thank you for your input. I'm aware of Node.js's performance limitations, but currently we do not have the time to rewrite it to C++ for example. Theoretically there should be a solution for the problem as the size of the sum of each entities data is not more than 10MB per second, even an old HDD could keep up with the writing speed with Node.js's IO handling.
